# Angular Material - Not working/Rendering w/o specific class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

So I'm learning Angular Material and decided to try from scratch rather than copying the code from the starter demo.

**Issue** - Angular Material not displaying unless I specify the element name in the class. e.g.

```html
            <md-button class="md-button md-raised loginBtnBackgroundColor toolbarFontColor">
                Login
            </md-button>

            <md-button class="md-raised registerBtnBackgroundColor toolbarFontColor">
                Register
            </md-button>
```

I will add HTML Code to see if anyone sees the issue. I have been trying to hours and fail to see why it's not working vs the starter app.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scoutlit - AngularMaterial</title>

    <!-- Anglar Material CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">

</head>

<body ng-app="angularMaterialDemo">
    <div layout="row">
        <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-whiteframe-z2">
            <!-- this isn't need i believe since we can add the class to the md toolbar <div class="md-toolbar-tools">-->
            <img src="http://scoutlit.com/images/logo-small.png" border="0" class="">
            <!-- fill up the space between left and right area -->
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-button md-raised loginBtnBackgroundColor toolbarFontColor">
                Login
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-raised registerBtnBackgroundColor toolbarFontColor">
                Register
            </md-button>
            <!--</div>-->
        </md-toolbar>
    </div>
    <!--
    <div ng-view>


    </div>
    -->

</body>

<!-- Angular JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>


<!-- My JS -->

<script src="assets/js/controllers/homepageController.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>



</html>
```

Image Link Below(I need reputation)
[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfPkY.png)

Comment: could you create a working plunkr with reproducible problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing your javascript code I guess you just forgot to import the `ngMaterial` module in your application, without it directives won't get fully rendered.

```
angular.module('angularMaterialDemo', ['ngMaterial']);
```

Why it works with the class is because the `md-button` directive does not do anything besides creating a button with the class `.md-button` inside of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It turns out I had a $injector:modulerr error which wasn't allowing angular to do its magic. The error was due to CDN i was pointing too was the latest angularjs which doesn't use ng-Route.

Comment: @Staeff you are a star! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a $injector:modulerr error which wasn't allowing angular to do its magic. The error was due to CDN i was pointing too was the latest angularjs which doesn't use ng-Route.